# RxJS 5 with Angular 2: Retry failed Observable but then forward error

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, rxjs5

When an HTTP request fails, I'd like to retry twice 1 second apart. If it fails again the third time, I'd like to forward that error to the Observers. I'm having trouble with that last part.

HTTP request from **DataService.get()**

```
return this.http.get(url,options)
    .retryWhen(errors => errors.delay(1000).take(2))
    .catch((res)=>this.handleError(res));
```

**Subscription**

```
this.dataSvc.get('/path').subscribe(
    res => console.log(res),
    err => console.error(err),
    () => console.log('Complete')
);
```

My server is setup to always return an error (status `400 Bad request`).

- I'd like the application to make a 2nd request, make a 3rd request, then throw the error to be caught by `this.handleError()`
- What actually happens: application  makes a 2nd request, makes a 3rd, then Observable completes without error ("*Complete*" printed to console)

`Angular 2 rc.6`, `RxJS 5 beta 11`, `Typescript 2.0.2`

Comment: Have a look at the answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928183/angular-2-rxjs-observable-retrywhen-filter-retry-on-error-status/41720854#41720854

Comment: @stely000 thanks for the link. Your solution is close to what I came up with (I wrote an answer below the same day I posted the question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used [the `scan` operator](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/scan.md):

```
return this.http.get(url,options)
    .retryWhen(errors => errors.delay(1000).scan((acc,source,index)=>{
        if(index) throw source;
    }))
    .catch((res)=>this.handleError(res));
```

The parameters of `scan()`:

- `acc`: an accumulator (think `Array.reduce()`). If you modify and return it, the new value will be provided as the `acc` parameter in the next execution
- `source`: the value (or exception) emitted by the previous operation (`delay()`, which itself forwards it from `errors`)
- `index`: Index of the currently emitted value (zero-based)

This makes 3 HTTP requests (Don't know why; I would have expected 2). On the 3rd failure, it throws `source` -- the error emitted -- to be caught by `handleError()`

Comment: if you give to the scan function a seed value the code makes exactly two HTTP calls