# Angular Http Get 404 Stops Further Calls

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404

Here is the brass tacks. I have this service call

```
this.searchTerm.valueChanges.debounceTime(400)
    .filter(searchTerm => { return searchTerm.length >= 3;})
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .switchMap((searchTerm) => this._scryfallService.getCards(searchTerm))
    .subscribe(data => this.cardSearchResults = data.data,
                err => this.cardSearchResults = [];
    );
```

And the back side of it looks like this

```
getCards(term: string): Observable<any> {
    let url = this.scryFallEndpoint + 'search?q="' + encodeURI(term) + '"+unique:prints+not:digital' ;
    return this._http.get(url)
    .map(res => res);
}
```

The service I make calls to will return a 404 if it can't find something using your search terms. If I get a 404 error the search stops working entirely and I have to refresh the page to do another search. If the search is successful I can just retype in my search box and it does another call just fine.

Summary: When the service call 404s it seems to prevent any other calls from being made

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could use `retry` or `retryWhen` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44911567/5695162)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should catch any error that the scryfallService throws and return a value that can be handled futher on. otherwise the observable will complete.

```
this.searchTerm.valueChanges.debounceTime(400)
    .filter(searchTerm => { return searchTerm.length >= 3;})
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .switchMap((searchTerm) => this._scryfallService.getCards(searchTerm).catch(err => Observable.of('error happened but please continue')))
    .subscribe(data => this.cardSearchResults = data.data,
                err => this.cardSearchResults = [];
    );
```

Comment: Thanks that is what I was looking for!