# Angular RxJs how to know if the take method has reached its limit

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, ionic3, httpclient

I am using **Angular** [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) in a **Ionic 3 App**. I also used [RxJs operators](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html) as a wrapper for my **http request**.

Here is my code below:

```
getDriverMeInfo() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.global.baseUrl}/me`)
    .retryWhen(e => e.do(err => { if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) console.log(err) }) 
    .delay(10000).take(10) // Delay after 10 seconds when an error occured and retry maximum of 10 takes
    ).toPromise()
  }
```

I call this function every time that app has successfully booted or loaded. The function retries when an error occured. What I want to happen is how would I know if the **http request** has reached 10 retries in the take method?

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No matter how many times it retries. It will only ever emit a single value, because `http.get` only emits a single value. So `take(10)` has no effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an RXjs RetryWhen with delay and limit on tries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44911251/how-to-create-an-rxjs-retrywhen-with-delay-and-limit-on-tries)

Comment: @cgTag thanks! It is working now. But there is a little problem. I am not able to catch the error on the caller of the function. The error logs only shows up automatically without any catch even thou I called the function without catch