# Writing tests for RxJS that uses retryWhen operator (understanding difference from retry operator)

Tags: unit-testing, rxjs, take, retry-logic

I'm trying to write tests for the following function that uses `retryWhen` operator:

```
// some API I'm using and mocking out in test
import { geoApi } from "api/observable";

export default function retryEpic(actions$) {
  return actions$.pipe(
    filter(action => action === 'A'),
    switchMap(action => {
      return of(action).pipe(
        mergeMap(() => geoApi.ipLocation$()),
        map(data => ({ data })),
        retryWhen(errors => {
          return errors.pipe(take(2));
        }),
      );
    }),
  );
}
```

The code is supposed to perform a request to some remote API `geoApi.ipLocation$()`. If it gets an error, it retries 2 times before giving up.

I have written the following test code that uses Jest and RxJS TestScheduler:

```
function basicTestScheduler() {
  return new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
  });
}

const mockApi = jest.fn();
jest.mock('api/observable', () => {
  return {
    geoApi: {
      ipLocation$: (...args) => mockApi(...args),
    },
  };
});

describe('retryEpic()', () => {
  it('retries fetching 2 times before succeeding', () => {
    basicTestScheduler().run(({ hot, cold, expectObservable, expectSubscriptions }) => {
      const actions$ = hot('-A');

      // The first two requests fail, third one succeeds
      const stream1 = cold('-#', {}, new Error('Network fail'));
      const stream2 = cold('-#', {}, new Error('Network fail'));
      const stream3 = cold('-r', { r: 123 });

      mockApi.mockImplementationOnce(() => stream1);
      mockApi.mockImplementationOnce(() => stream2);
      mockApi.mockImplementationOnce(() => stream3);

      expectObservable(retryEpic(actions$)).toBe('----S', {
        S: { data: 123 },
      });

      expectSubscriptions(stream1.subscriptions).toBe('-^!');
      expectSubscriptions(stream2.subscriptions).toBe('--^!');
      expectSubscriptions(stream3.subscriptions).toBe('---^');
    });
  });
});
```

This test fails.

However, when I replace `retryWhen(...)` with simply `retry(2)`, then the test succeeds.

Looks like I don't quite understand how to implement `retry` with `retryWhen`. I suspect this `take(2)` is closing the stream and kind of preventing everything from continuing. But I don't quite understand it.

I actually want to write some additional logic inside `retryWhen()`, but first I need to understand how to properly implement `retry()` with `retryWhen()`. Or perhaps that's actually not possible?

### Additional resources

My implementation of `retryWhen` + `take` was based on this SO answer:

- [How to create an RXjs RetryWhen with delay and limit on tries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44911567/15982)

Official docs:

- [retryWhen](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/retryWhen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `retryWhen` for those two purposes, one to have your logic in it and the second is the retry numbers you'd like to give it (no need to use `retry` operator):

```
// some API I'm using and mocking out in test
import { geoApi } from "api/observable";

export default function retryEpic(actions$) {
  return actions$.pipe(
    filter(action => action === 'A'),
    switchMap(action => {
      return of(action).pipe(
        mergeMap(() => geoApi.ipLocation$()),
        map(data => ({ data })),
        retryWhen(errors =>
          errors.pipe(
            mergeMap((error, i) => {
              if (i === 2) {
                throw Error();
              }
              // return your condition code
            })
          )
        )
      )
    }),
  );
}
```

Here is a simple [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rxjs-retry-when) of that.

As for understanding this logic:

[`retryWhen`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/retryWhen) and [`retry`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/retry) operators, according to the Official docs you've referenced:

> resubscribing to the source Observable (if no error or complete executes)

This is why you can't pipe `retry` and `retryWhen` together. You can say that these operators are a chain breakers...

Comment: Aha... I see now. I misunderstood the referenced SO post from which I took this concept of using `take()` inside `retryWhen()`. I concluded that I simply need to close the errors stream inside `retryWhen`, but inside that post the use of `take` was more of an implementation details - and the stream was finished by appending an error-throwing stream.

The takeaway being that to finish retryWhen cycle, an error must be thrown.